# Installing couchbase in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: couchbase

I havent been able to start my newly installed couchbase-server_2.0.1. I've spent more that 2 hours trying to get couchbase-server work in my local machine.

By the way i'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I tried removing it using this command dpkg -r couch-server and even removing it using my Synaptic Package Manager then deleted couchbase folder located at /opt/ then reinstall it again. But same result always appear to me saying *** Failed to start couchbase-server: timed out**

Oh by the way I checked my RAM size and hard-drive capacity, im good in that side.

Any of you guys encountered this problem? This is taking a lot of my time. T__T

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? In your logs? Would you be willing to send your log file to Couchbase for us to take a look at? This sounds like a simple error, and should be easily overcome. Diagnosing it right now isn't strictly possible, as it could be a Firewall problem etc, but your log file should clear everything up for us.

Comment: Which raises an interesting point, @WonderingCoder, you should edit your question to include some bits of logfiles.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of important things when installing CouchBase 2

1. Swappiness must be between 0 and 10... I run at 0
2. Ulimit -n must be bumped a bit. I run our servers at 16384

Between those 2 you should get a working server. I also would not run CouchBase alongside any other software